# The gateway cannot be ping under the bridge mode of CentOS7

Tags: centos7, gateway, vmware-workstation, bridge

everyone!In bridge mode,I can ping any other address under the gateway,but i can not ping gateway,Of course, the outer net is not good either.I looked for a lot of schemes, but none of them worked.
Here are some of my configurations

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens33
UUID=6082d1cf-bdde-4bda-bcc2-338aad8788d1
DEVICE=ens33
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.20.121
PREFIX=24
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.20.1
DNS1=192.168.20.1
```

When i use `route -n`,it shows up.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens33
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 ens33
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens33
```

But I use DHCP to get the IP automatically, which can connect to the gateway and the extranet.
so,is there something here that I didn't set but DHCP set for me?
My guess is that the MAC is the problem. 192.168.20.121 and the 192.168.20.211 automatically obtained in this segment use the same MAC address.
static:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:298a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:83:29:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21643  bytes 1769329 (1.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3363  bytes 421138 (411.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

automatically:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.211  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:298a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:83:29:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22582  bytes 1859583 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3627  bytes 453704 (443.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.The UUID sets the MAC address, which is associated with 192.168.20.211.
When i use the static ip 192.168.20.121 with the same MAC address,there comes the problem.
So I deleted that line, restarted the network, and it worked.